# The methods of figure size adjustment don't work in RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

Recently I used RMarkdown to create a website with a `selectInput` box.

Everything gose well but I have a small question and I tried several methods but it doesn't work.

I want to change the output figure size using `fig.width` and `fig.height`. And I know the default value is `fig.width=7` and `fig.height=5` and I'd like to make the plot a little bit higher.
However I tried this and also parameters like `fig.fullwidth=TRUE` , `par(mar = c())` , `out.width` and `out.height` . All of them changed nothing.

So I don't know if there is something wrong with my code chunk?

I need your help. Plz give me some advice.

Here is my reproducile code and data in Rmd.

````
---
title: "123"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
##    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
```
abc {.sidebar data-width=373} 
=========================================================

```{r}
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

inputPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol", 
        "Select Gene Symbol:", 
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 360,
        selected = "Sele"
      )
)

actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "plot1")
actionButton(inputId = "plot2", label = "plot2")

```


Home {.tabset}
===================================

```{r ,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,echo=FALSE,out.height=8}
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1,
                      {
                        req(input$selectGeneSymbol)
    ggplot(data =mean_data, aes(x = Name, y =.data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")
  })
renderPlot({
p1()
})
```


```{r ,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,echo=FALSE,out.height=10}
p2 <- eventReactive(input$plot2,{
    req(input$selectGeneSymbol)
                        req(input$selectGeneSymbol)
    ggplot(data =mean_data, aes(x = Name, y =.data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")
})
renderPlot({
p2()
})
```
````

Comment: Can somebody give me some advice ?

Comment: Who could help me ?